# Registering a presenter class to EventBus (android MVP)

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm using greenrobot's EventBus in my android apps and I absolutely like it.

However, now I'd like to seperate the logic from my fragments by using presenters (MVP).

Is the following possible and is it **useful**?

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment implements IMyFragment {

  IMyPresenter mPresenter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(...) {
    mPresenter = new MyPresenter(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    // EventBus.getDefault().register(mPresenter); // register presenter to bus
    mPresenter.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    // EventBus.getDefault().unregister(mPresenter); // unregister presenter from bus
    mPresenter.pause();
  }

  @Override
  public void doSomething() { // gets called via presenter
    // ...
  }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class MyPresenter implements IMyPresenter {

  IMyFragment mFragment;

  // constructor to inject fragment
  public MyPresenter(IMyFragment mFragment) {
    this.mFragment = mFragment;
  }

  // handle event
  public void onEvent(SomeEvent event) {
    mFragment.doSomething();
  }

  public void resume() {
    EventBus.getDefault.register(this);
  }
  public void pause() {
    EventBus.getDefault.unregister(this);
  }
}
```

Does this make sense?

Or is it even dangerous regarding unregistering the presenter from the bus and the complex fragment lifecycle?

**Edit:** Moved bus registration to presenter itself (Thanks to Nicklas).

Any more comments on this architecture?

Answer (score 4):

You're putting too much responsibility on the View. What you want to do instead is have your Presenter expose a `resume()` and `pause()` method, and call those in your View. In those methods you'll `register()` and `unregister()` on the `EventBus`.

This puts all the event-handling code in your Presenter. It also means that you can change the event mechanism you use in your presenter, at any time, without having to change a line of code in your View.

In MVP, the only object you'll want to call non-view-related methods on, from the View, is the associated Presenters.

Comment: If you also delgate lifecycle code away from the Activity then you have effectiviely replaced  your activity with your presenter object. I think if you apply SRP then Activity should implement its own lifecycle handling code.